# Cakephp Custom Helper containing Javascript

Tags: javascript, cakephp, helper

I created a helper for my cakephp project. The helper creates a custom input field with a lot of complicated Javascript running at the backend of the input field. I get an error when I try to run my project though.

Code in my DropDownHelper.php file:

```
class DropDownHelper extends AppHelper {
?>
<!-- JQUERY LOADING -->
<script type="text/javascript"     src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery.curCSS = jQuery.css;
</script>
<!-- JQUERY LOADING -->

<!-- STYLE SHEET -->
<style>
  Some custom styles.
</style>
<!-- STYLE SHEET -->

<!-- SCRIPT -->
<script >
  My main Script.
</script>
<!-- SCRIPT -->

<!-- HTML -->
  Some HTML
<!-- HTML -->
<?php
}
?>
```

Part of my Controller:

```
class PortfoliosController extends AppController {
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
public $helpers  = array('DropDown');
```

And finally, my View:

```
echo $this->DropDown->input('Clients');
```

The error says:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION in /...../app/View/Helper/DropDownHelper.php on line 34

Lime 34 is Where I close off the php, right before my scripts, css, and html.
i.e.

```
class DropDownHelper extends AppHelper {
?>
```

Line 34 is the line that says "?>".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out myself. All that has to happen is this:

```
class DropDownHelper extends AppHelper {
public function functionName()
  {
    All the scripts, css, html
  }
}
```

So basically you have to put everything inside a function.